# Posting Coordinates to Database from Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, html, sql, laravel, google-maps

Edit: I solved the problem. Leaving it up in case someone needs something similar in the future.

I am trying to use google map api to get coordinates and save the information in a database. If the user drags the marker then a form is updated with the information. User can also enter the information manually in the form if she wants and the map will be updated with a new marker. Then the user can click submit and the information will be saved in the database.

```html
<form action="{{ route('YOUR_ROUTE') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">

<div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                <div id="map-location"></div>
                            </div>

{{--                            visibility, lat, lng, location --}}

                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="location_name" id="location_name" placeholder="Location">

                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude" placeholder="Latitude" style="max-width: 50%;">

                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="longitude" id="longitude" placeholder="Longitude" style="max-width: 50%;">


                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
                        
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    
                    
                    
<script>
        //initialise and add the map
        function initMap(){
//    location of midtown manhattan
            var midtown = {lat: 40.7549, lng: -73.9840};
//    the maps centered at midtown
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-location'),{zoom:17, center:midtown});
//    the marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: midtown, map: map, draggable: true});

            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

            // Try HTML5 geolocation.
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var pos = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };

                    marker.setPosition(pos);

                    map.setCenter(pos);
                }, function() {
                    handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                });
            } else {
                // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            }

        function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
        }

            //    dragged event of the marker
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(){
                var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
                var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
                var address;

                $('#latitude').val(lat);
                $('#longitude').val(lng);

                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({latLng: marker.getPosition()}, function(result,status){
                    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                        address = result[0].formatted_address;
                        // console.log(address);
                        $('#location_name').val(address);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                    }
                });
            });

        //    when the place is changed in the location box the map updates
            searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.querySelector( '#location_name' ));

            google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function(){
                var places = searchBox.getPlaces(),
                bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                for(var i = 0; place = places[i]; i++){
                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                }

                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                map.setZoom(15);

                var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
                var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();

                $('#latitude').val(lat);
                $('#longitude').val(lng);
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Solved the problem.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, I encourage you to either delete the question (as the original poster, you should have this power) or to post your solution as an answer and accept that answer. We don't tag as solved in titles here.

Comment: How did you solve it? Post your answer below and accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my first post with the code that is working for me.

I couldn't update the map with the information from the form because I didn't include the places library while loading the Maps JavaScript API.

I couldn't see the updated coordinates after dragging the map marker because I didn't enable the geocoding api and didn't create a billing account with google cloud. I also restricted my API key.

Hope this helps.